# Loading Ruby scripts in SketchUp: LoadError: (eval):0:in `load': no such file to load

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have been trying to manually load Ruby scripts into SketchUp manually, using load. I always get an error back saying the file is non existent even though it is there in the directory.

Here is a sample of my code:
`load "H:Document\sclf_color_by_z_1.6.1_1.rbz"`

and the error messages:

> Error: LoadError: (eval):0:in `load': no such file to load -- H:Document clf_color_by_z_1.6.1_1.rbz>
>   (eval)
>   (eval):0

Answer (score 1):

Three issues here:

1. `H:Document\sclf_color_by_z_1.6.1_1.rbz` is not a valid path. After the Drive specifier `H:` you you should have a separator: `\` - like so: `H:\Document\sclf_color_by_z_1.6.1_1.rbz`
2. Beware escape characters in strings when you program. `\` is such a character.
   To correct your string you'd have to have something like this:
   `"H:\\Document\\sclf_color_by_z_1.6.1_1.rbz"`
   https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Escape_sequences
   However, note that the convention for Ruby is to use forward slashes - even on Windows: `"H:/Document/clf_color_by_z_1.6.1_1.rbz"`
3. You are trying to load an RBZ file here. This is *not* the same as an RB file. An RBZ is a packaged SketchUp extension (actually a ZIP file). To programmatically install an RBZ you must use `Sketchup.install_from_archive("H:/Document/clf_color_by_z_1.6.1_1.rbz")`
   http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/sketchup#install_from_archive

Note that `Sketchup.install_from_archive` is nothing like `load` - it permanently installs the extension to SketchUp where as `load` would be just for that session.

Whenever you have a filepath that you think should be on disk - as the system whether it can find it: `File.exist?("H:\Document\sclf_color_by_z_1.6.1_1.rbz")` If that return `false` you know you need to carefully check your path again checking for syntax errors and typos.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use [`File.join()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-join) method. In your case:
2. You can't use `load` for a `.rbz` file but you can use [`Sketchup.install_from_archive()`](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/sketchup#install_from_archive) as [thomthom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486990/thomthom) said

So in your case your can simply do:

```
file = File.join( 'H:', 'Document' , 'sclf_color_by_z_1.6.1_1.rbz' )
Sketchup.install_from_archive file
```